# Like Operator is not hash-able - Teradata

Tags: database, indexing, teradata

Like Operator is not hash-able. That's why Primary indexes and secondary indexes are not effective for it. Any Logical Reason why Like operator is not hash able? Thanks

Comment: How will you calculate a hash value if you don't know which data will be hashed?

Comment: right that makes sense.